# Is it possible to render a react component only when a prop is initialized?

Tags: reactjs, components, render, arcgis, react-functional-component

I am trying to pass a prop **search** to my AddressList component.

```
<div className="addresses">
                {search && <AddressList onAddressSelect={addressSelectFunction}
                                       addresses={app.addresses}
                                       update={updateChild}
                                       searchRef={searchRef}
                                       search={search}
                                       searchCompleteHandler={searchCompleteHandler}/> }
            </div>
```

The problem is, that the prop is probably not initialized during rendering.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    loadModules(["esri/Map",
        "esri/views/MapView",
        "esri/Graphic",
        "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
        "esri/widgets/Search",
        "esri/tasks/Locator",
        "esri/geometry/Point",
        "esri/tasks/RouteTask",
        "esri/tasks/support/RouteParameters",
        "esri/tasks/support/FeatureSet",
        "esri/geometry/geometryEngine",
        "esri/geometry/support/webMercatorUtils"])
        .then(([Map, MapView, Graphic, GraphicsLayer, Search, Locator, Point, RouteTask, RouteParameters, FeatureSet, geometryEngine, webMercatorUtils]) => {
            //...initialize other stuff
            search = new Search({
                view: view,
                container: searchRef.current,
                sources: [
                    {
                        locator: new Locator({url: "https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer"}),
                        countryCode: "LTU",
                        name: "Custom Geocoding Service"
                    }
                ],
                includeDefaultSources: false
//....});
```

Is it possible to make the child component AddressList render only when **search** is initialized?

Comment: If you add the `search` prop as a dependency of the `useEffect` hook it will only run when that prop is initialized or updated.

Comment: I don't understand. All of the code I posted here is from the Map component. The search variable is supposed to be initialized like in the code below and then passed as a prop to the AddressList component like in the code above. The problem is, that all of the code that goes before and after useEffect and loadModules, get's executed way before useEffect and loadModules does. That's why the search varialbe is not initialized and null is passed. Is there a way to make the program wait for the prop to be initialized before rendering the child component?

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-render the component.

```
const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
useEffect(()=>{
!loaded && loadModules(["esri/Map",
    "esri/views/MapView",
    "esri/Graphic",
    "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
    "esri/widgets/Search",
    "esri/tasks/Locator",
    "esri/geometry/Point",
    "esri/tasks/RouteTask",
    "esri/tasks/support/RouteParameters",
    "esri/tasks/support/FeatureSet",
    "esri/geometry/geometryEngine",
    "esri/geometry/support/webMercatorUtils"])
    .then(([Map, MapView, Graphic, GraphicsLayer, Search, Locator, Point, RouteTask, RouteParameters, FeatureSet, geometryEngine, webMercatorUtils]) => {
        //...initialize other stuff
        search = new Search({
            view: view,
            container: searchRef.current,
            sources: [
                {
                    locator: new Locator({url: "https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer"}),
                    countryCode: "LTU",
                    name: "Custom Geocoding Service"
                }
            ],
            includeDefaultSources: false
            setLoaded(true)
//....});
```

Comment: If I re-render the component, the map rerenders as well. In this case I can't rerender the parent component

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you. After putting in a lot of work trying to get arcgis to work with react, I gave up and went back to plain javascript. The issue is probably too deep to be discussed on this website.